# How can Rpi3B+ read the output of the 801s vibration sensor module?

Tags: pi-3b+, sensor, database

Currently I'm trying to do a project using rpi 3b+ with 801s vibration sensor using this tutorial https://github.com/Shmoopty/rpi-appliance-monitor#notification-settings

I'm beginner with rpi and python so I'm having a problem to send/keep the data into firebase. I have been looking for tutorial and code for using sensor to send the sensor data to firebase but nothing that suitable for my project. If there any solution for this problem would be a big help for me. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  You tutorial is a complicated smart phone app project, getting vibration sensing module, and put it in a database. The project can be divided into two parts: (1) How to get sensor data, (2) How to store and access info in database.  For part (1) You need to decide to get analog or digital data.  If you want analog data, you need a ADC, analog to digital converter.  You can easily find Arduino sample programs. The references are: / to continue, ...

Comment: (1) AliExpress Vibration Sensor Module 801S Vibration Analog Output Sensitivity LM393 - US$2.1
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32808658968.html

(2) 801S Vibration Sensor Module (SE040) User Manual - IduIno
https://produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1400000-1499999/001485302-da-01-en-IDUINO_SE040_VIBRATIONS_SENSOR_MODUL.pdf

Comment: @tlfong01 Ohh i see. I just want to send a simple data whether the machine is started or not. So i just want to know how i can send the data to firebase? I know it is sound complicated but do i need just simply install firebase and add POST to the script inside of rpi? I'm sorry for asking too much questions

Comment: Hi @QQila, it is good to give a big picture, then zoom into details where you might expect problems.  I prefer you ask as many SHORT questions as possible, as long as they are related.  As I used to say, you first look at the big elephant, and then eat it, bite by bite.  In your case, you might have altogether 20 or more short questions, eg: (Q1) How can Rpi3B+ read 801 sensor data? (Q2) How to store read data into an python array? (3) How to store array data to a log/text file? ... (Q20) How to use smart phone to get the organized, statistical info charts, etc, in the cloud database? ...

Comment: And often we look at the first and last step.  First step is how to start, Last step is actually the goal, which is sort of project user requirements and functional specifications.  You might also have user constraints such as eg, (1) I have only 3 weeks to finish my project, and my supervisor insists to use 801, (2) My school's FireBase is already working, I just need to use the API's to talk to it, ...  Just brainstorming, you might like to comment and make counter suggestions, ...

Comment: so your question title is too broad for this Q&A forum. I would like to take liberty now to narrow down your board question to just reading the senor output.  If you agree on my modified question (counter suggestion welcome!), then I can try to make an answer.  In the mean time, you can of course ask more short questions on perhaps vibration data analysis, statistics, and real time cloud based FireBase front end and back end stuff.

Comment: Hi @QQlia. You, the Rpi python newbie, need to build up basic Rpi hardware and software knowledge/skills.  I would recommend to do the following two DIY projects: (1) Use python to blink a LED, (2) Use python to read a button. You can easy find blink LED programs and try them.  For reading a button, there are too many demo programs to select.  I would suggest you the three tutorials in Ref 5, 6, 7.  I guess you need two weeks to catch up.  So I will wait for you to report your progress in blink led / read button before I carry on my discussions.  Happy programming, good luck, and cheers! :)

Comment: Hi @QQlia, BAD NEWS. I found one problem.  I read the vibration datasheet and found that the switching cycle lifespan is only 200,000 cycles.  In other words, it is perhaps OK for a washing machine or clothes driver whose frequency is only 50/60Hz, and you don't operate that often.  Now if you machine is 24 x 7, motor driven, they frequency might be higher that 50Hz, so the vibration sensor's lifespan might be much shorter than you expected.  You might like to consider other non spring type sensors, or mercury tilt sensors which should have a much higher switching cycle lifespan .

Answer (score 2):

When you have solved the firedatabae you will meet another.

The URL you refere to have a serious error.

The "801s vibration sensor" have one digital output that is triggered depending on the level of vibrations. Not suitable for meassurements but well suited for infication/alarm.

The outher output is a analoge level the indicate the level of vibrations, but the challange is that Raspberry Pi doesn't have a A/D (Analog to Digital) converter so you need a external A/D that can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a sensor there are two major options:
1. You have to handle it through I2C
2. You have to read the analog or digital signal from that sensor(basically Vcc,Out,GND)

What ever you do if you are going to use this on Raspberry GPIO then you must maintain a voltage of 3.3V on each pin. Otherwise the board will burn. Maybe this answer will help you understand things better.