# How does the raspberry shake software work?

Tags: raspbian

Correct me if I'm wrong. I just need an sd card with Raspbian installed and the software for raspberry shake.

Because I want to use my own sd card, not the one Raspberry Shake came with. But I'm having trouble in finding the Raspberry Shake image download. When I check their GitLab repository and click the download button, it refers me to this link https://gitlab.com/raspberryShake-public/raspShake-SD-img/raw/master/raspishake-release.zip but I'm getting an Error 404.

Is there some kind of known problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @olivakyle, Ah let me see. I just now visited the official RpiShake shop and read the product info: (1) RS1D Board Only USD100
https://shop.raspberryshake.org/product/iot-home-earth-monitor-board-only-rs-1d/

(2) RS1D without RPi $215
https://shop.raspberryshake.org/product/iot-home-earth-monitor-rpi-not-included-rs-1d/, It is pretty obvious you have the option of (1) Buying an extra SD card preprogrammed with the Shake software, or (2) Download and install the shake software and install it yourself. If the download site gives you Error 404, then you should ask the customer service.

Comment: I am interested to try DIY version, But I feel very uncomfortable reading the sales page saying that there are NO reviews. Is it a start up project not properly started? I googled and found a year 2016 start up project review. Have your read any more up to date reviews, or STEM school blogs about it? Shake Review:https://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/raspberry-shake-seismograph/

Comment: I read the Starter Ad and found it interesting. I would like to know more about how many schools are using it now: 
Raspberry Shake Your Personal Seismograph Starter 2016
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/angelrodriguez/raspberry-shake-your-personal-seismograph?ref=dfg

Comment: The following two posts might give you more updated info on how schools and makers are talking about geophones: (1) Raspi-powered seismometer/seismograph
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=3731

(2) How to connect a geophone to RaspberryPi?
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105643/how-to-connect-a-geophone-to-raspberrypi I spent some two hours reading and googling and found the subject very interesting.